# Image view moves to aside when scrolling vertically in scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I've got a view controller that has a UIView (featuredStoryView) and inside that view, I've added a scroll view (scrollView) and inside the scroll view, I've added an ImageView (bookCover), one on top of the other. Here is the code for all of those elements:

```
func setupFeaturedStoryView() {

    featuredStoryView.backgroundColor = .white
    featuredStoryView.layer.cornerRadius = 12

    // Let the user tap on the featured story image view
    featuredStoryView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(featuredStoryViewTapped))
    featuredStoryView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    view.addSubview(featuredStoryView)
    addFeaturedStoryViewConstraints()

}

func setupScrollView() {

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 10/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 0.5)
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    featuredStoryView.addSubview(scrollView)

    // Add the constraints to the scroll view
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func setupBookCover() {

    bookCover.backgroundColor = .yellow
    bookCover.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    bookCover.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    scrollView.addSubview(bookCover)
    addBookCoverConstraints()

}

// Add the constraints to the featured story view
func addFeaturedStoryViewConstraints() {

    featuredStoryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    featuredStoryView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -130).isActive = true
    featuredStoryView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    featuredStoryView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    featuredStoryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true

}

// Add constraints to the book cover
func addBookCoverConstraints() {

    bookCover.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bookCover.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bookCover.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bookCover.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bookCover.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

When you tap on the featuredStoryView, the following code snippet runs:

```
@objc func featuredStoryViewTapped() {

    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1500

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.6, dampingRatio: 0.8) {
        self.featuredStoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.bookCover.frame = CGRect(x: self.featuredStoryView.frame.midX - (bookCoverWidth / 2), y: 90, width: bookCoverWidth, height: bookCoverHeight)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    animator.startAnimation()

}
```

Now take a look at this Gif:

[image: View controller]

The problem here is, when I scroll, the yellow imageView(bookCover) moves to the top left corner, why does this happen? It should just go up with the scroll view. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly due to mixing auto-layout / constraints with explicitly setting frames and contentSize. It would help if you post the full code so we could see exactly what's happening - see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can not set frame directly like `self.featuredStoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)` and `contentSize` like `scrollView.contentSize.height = 1500` in auto layout. So try to set constraints as per your requirement.